# html tags are getting stripped out on storing to database, wordpress custom post type, editor

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field2'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field3'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data =   sanitize_text_field($_POST['myplugin_new_field']);
    $my_data2 =  sanitize_text_field($_POST['myplugin_new_field2']);
    $my_data3 =  sanitize_text_field($_POST['myplugin_new_field3']);

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key2', $my_data2 );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key3', $my_data3 );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

i am using default editor, all html tags are getting stripped out on storing.

Comment: Yes, [calling `sanitize_text_field` will strip out HTML tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field). Function works as advertised. I guess you want to use some other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [sanitize_text_field()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field) strips all tags, according to the Wordpress Function Reference.

> Checks for invalid UTF-8, Convert single < characters to entity, strip all tags, remove line breaks, tabs and extra white space, strip octets.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was with sanitize_text_field() function

Comment: @afsy glad you were able to fix it.  Please mark this answer as correct if you feel it helped you.